# Expand and contract views smoothly

Tags: android, user-interface, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

In the Material Design video, views expand and contract really smoothly. I tried to achieve that back in the days with the old Android APIs and it was really costly and slow.

Is there any new APIs in Android-L to achieve those effects?

Video with the effect http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8TXgCzxEnw#t=26

Comment: `Is there any new API to achieve those effects?` Yes, the new "L" API level?! Your question contradicts itself.

Comment: I forgot to clarify that I was asking for APIs within Android-L

Answer (score 8):

You can use the new Animation APIs in android-L to easily create most of the effects you see in this video.

**Reveal Effect**
You can animate a clipping circle to reveal or hide a view.
This is what you see when the Play button is clicked in the video. The button expands and reveals the media player.

Code to reveal a hidden view ([source](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/animations.html#reveal))

```
// previously invisible view
View myView = findViewById(R.id.my_view);

// get the center for the clipping circle
int cx = (myView.getLeft() + myView.getRight()) / 2;
int cy = (myView.getTop() + myView.getBottom()) / 2;

// get the final radius for the clipping circle
int finalRadius = myView.getWidth();

// create and start the animator for this view
// (the start radius is zero)
ValueAnimator anim =
    ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);
anim.start();
```

You can find the code to hide a view if you follow the above link.

**Activity Enter and Exit Transitions**
You can specify how views enter or exit a scene.

The currently supported transitions are explode, slide and fade. Any transition that extends the `android.transition.Visibility` is also supported.

Many examples can be seen throughout the video.

Code for an explode exit transition ([source](http://developer.android.com/preview/material/get-started.html#animations))

```
// inside your activity
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);

// set an exit transition
getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
```

**Activity Shared Elements Transition**
You can specify how an element which is shared between two activities can transition between them.

Supported transitions are:

- changeBounds - Animates the changes in layout bounds of target views.
- changeClipBounds - Animates the changes in clip bounds of target views.
- changeTransform - Animates the changes in scale and rotation of target views.
- changeImageTransform - Animates changes in size and scale type for an image view.

To make a shared element transition you need to do the following: ([source](http://developer.android.com/preview/material/animations.html))

- Enable window content transitions in your style.
- Specify a shared elements transition in your style.
- Define your transition as an XML resource.
- Assign a common name to the shared elements in both layouts with the android:viewName attribute.
- Use the `ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation` method.

  ```
  // get the element that receives the click event
  final View imgContainerView = findViewById(R.id.img_container);

  // get the common element for the transition in this activity
  final View androidRobotView = findViewById(R.id.image_small);

  // define a click listener
  imgContainerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
          // create the transition animation - the images in the layouts
          // of both activities are defined with android:viewName="robot"
          ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions
              .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, androidRobotView, "robot");
          // start the new activity
          startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
      }
  });
  ```

One animation I haven't figured out yet is the expand/contract animation inside the same activity, which can be seen in the calendar app.

The only thing I can say about it is that they are using elevation since we can see a shadow. I'll try to hack at it a little and see if I can recreate it.

Comment: Nice write up. What I'm asking is how views expand & contract like in the video linked, second 26.

Comment: Somehow when I opened the link, the video started from the beginning and I didn't notice that you were linking to a specific time. This is the calendar animation I mentioned at the end of my answer.

Comment: oh! I see! apparently is not documented anywhere. Tried to dig in the documentation but nothing :/

Comment: Just to add a bit, moveImage has been changed to changeImageTransform. All L to 21 API changes are available here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/preview-21/changes.html